# MYSQL select oldest record nearest to given date but not older

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

I have a table with records belonging to different users.

Table:

```
RECORD_ID     USER_ID     DATE_CREATED
1             5           08/05/12
2             5           08/04/12
3             10          08/05/12
4             10          08/02/12
5             10          08/01/12
```

Query:

```
SELECT user_id, MIN(date_created) as date_created
FROM (entries) 
GROUP BY user_id
```

The query returns the oldest record for each users.

```
RECORD_ID     USER_ID     DATE_CREATED
2             5           08/04/12
5             10          08/01/12
```

How can I select the oldest record nearest to a given date but not older?  Something along the lines of...

```
SELECT oldest record > given oldest record
WHERE oldest record NOT =< given oldest record
```

For example a query returns all records for user `10`:

```
RECORD_ID     USER_ID     DATE_CREATED
3             10          08/05/12
4             10          08/02/12
5             10          08/01/12
```

The given date for user `10` is `08/02/12`. Now I have to select the next oldest record above `08/02/12`.

That would be `08/05/12` and never records below that unless it reached the top. How is this possible in MYSQL?

Comment: What kind of field is the date stored in? Is unix time stamp or something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let `$date_given` have the given date.

```
SELECT user_id, MIN(date_created) as date_created
FROM (entries) 
WHERE date_created > $date_given
GROUP BY user_id
LIMIT 1
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with a combination of `WHERE` and `LIMIT`:

```
SELECT user_id, content, MIN(date_created) as date_created
FROM (entries) 
WHERE date_created > '2012-08-02'
GROUP BY user_id
LIMIT 1
```

There `WHERE` statement will handle the date issue. The `LIMIT` statement will keep your results down to one row. Obviously you can change `2012-08-02'` to be a variable or whatever date you need.

Answer (score 2):

How about

Select user_id, date_created from entries where date_created > somedate order by date_created desc limit 1

Answer (score 0):

Here is the query to select nearest records for all users with record_id's. Just change '08/02/12' to date you need:

```
select 
    entries.record_id,entries.user_id, entries.Date_created 
from entries
join
(select 
      user_id,min(Date_created) minDate 
           from entries 
           where Date_Created>'08/02/12' 
      group by user_id
) minDates on (entries.user_id=minDates.user_id) 
              and 
              (entries.Date_created=minDates.minDate)
```

Comment: Thanks I don't understand why you're selecting two times and joining the same tables.

Comment: This query outputs not only Date_created but also a full record from table with this Date_created

Comment: Maybe I'm not understanding but that should also work using an `AND` clause in 1 join.